# Azure Function after deployment on Azure Portal giving error: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')

Tags: entity-framework-core, azure-functions, connection-string

I have deployed an Azure Function on Azure Portal but it is giving me error while I am inserting data into the database via Entity Framework.

> Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')

My Startup.cs File:

```
[assembly: WebJobsStartup(typeof(Startup))]
namespace DataMonitorAzureFunction
{
    public class Startup : IWebJobsStartup
    {
        private IConfiguration configuration;
        public void Configure(IWebJobsBuilder builder)
        {
            configuration = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
            string? connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("RSMDataContext");
            builder.Services.AddDbContext<RSMDataStagingContext>(
                options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
        }
    }
}
```

local.settings.json:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "ftpdatadirectory": "*******"
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "RSMDataContext": "Server=******"
  }
}
```

I have also added the connection string in the application configuration on azure portal with the same name "RSMDataContext".

[image]

**Update:**

I have changed my local.settings.json and startup.cs files but I am still seeing the same error after deployment.

local.settings.json:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "ftpdatadirectory": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=****",
    "RSMDataContext": "Server=*****"
  }
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
[assembly: WebJobsStartup(typeof(Startup))]
namespace DataMonitorAzureFunction
{
    public class Startup : IWebJobsStartup
    {
        private IConfiguration configuration;
        public void Configure(IWebJobsBuilder builder)
        {
            configuration = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
            string? connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("RSMDataContext");
            builder.Services.AddDbContext<RSMDataStagingContext>(
                options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
        }
    }
}
```

Configuration settings:

[image: Updated Configuration Image]

The error I am getting:

[image]

Comment: The value `RSMDataContext` will be available under EnvironmentVariables in KUDU Console with prefix of the DB Name.Ex: `MYsQL_RSMDataContext`.

Comment: Try to get the value from Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable and check once.

Comment: I didn't get your first comment.

Comment: The key-value which you have added in Azure Configuration => Connection String section is available in KUDU Console.[Image1](https://i.imgur.com/omzVRTj.png) [Image2](https://i.imgur.com/PSdNlJZ.png)

Comment: I've tried to get the value from Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ConnectionStrings:RSMDataContext") but it's getting the value locally but not on Azure Portal. Getting the same error.

Comment: Is your environment variable name same ?Are you able to see the value in kudu?

Comment: I don't use kudu but yes I have changed the configuration name as you showed in the Kudu. Do I need to change it in the environment variable as well like this :
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SQLAZURECONNSTR_RSMDataContext")??

Comment: Please check my local.settings.json file it's same as mentioned in that.

Comment: Can you please add an answer to this question with brief snapshots of what you are trying to explain?

Comment: Yes you need to change the name in environment variable as well.

Comment: Use `AddEnvironmentVariables()` in your Startup code

Comment: What is the Azure Function Version you are using?

Comment: Hi Can you please add a brief answer to explain what you are trying to explain here? Like can you add a code snippet. I am unable to understand like this in the comments section.

Comment: I am using Azure Function with Blob Trigger (.Net 6 Framework)

Comment: Ok..Will try to repro with your code and let you know.

Comment: AFAIK,the connectionString in `local.settings.json` has to be added in the values section itself.Directly add `RSMDataContext": "Server=******"` in values section.

Comment: Please share your `.csproj` file once.

Answer (score 0):

When we set the value in `Azure Function` => `Configuration` => `Connection String`, the value will be available in the Environment Variables in KUDU Console as shown below.

[image]

This can be seen only if we deploy the Function App to Windows.

```cs
.AddEnvironmentVariables()
```

- `.AddEnvironmentVariables()` adds the Environment Variables to the ConfigBuilder.

[image]

Check the below code to retrieve ConnectionString.

***Way1:***

If you have set the values in `local.settings,json` as below (Currently you have stored)

```cs
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "RSMDataContext": "Server=SQLServer.database.windows.net;Database=SQLDB;User Id=MyName;Password=******;Encrypt=true;Connection Timeout=30;"
  }
}
```

Then use the below line of code.

```cs
string connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("RSMDataContext");
```

***Way2:***

- If you have set the connection String under Values section

```cs
 "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
        "RSMDataContext": "Server=SQLServer.database.windows.net;Database=SQLDB;User Id=MyName;Password=******;Encrypt=true;Connection Timeout=30;"
  },
```

then use this code.

```cs
 string connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("RSMDataContext");
```

***OR***

```cs
 string connectionString = configuration.GetSection("RSMDataContext").Value;
```

To Retrieve the value using `GetSection` or using Environment Variable, we need to set the key-value in App Settings instead of Connection String in Azure Function.

[image]

[image]
***My `Startup.cs` file:***

```cs
 public void Configure(IWebJobsBuilder builder)
{
     //        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
     //.SetBasePath(Environment.CurrentDirectory)
     //.AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
     //.AddEnvironmentVariables()
     //.Build();

     var configuration = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
     string connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("RSMDataContext");


     string ConnValue = configuration.GetConnectionString("RSMDataContext");

     string EnvValue = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("RSMDataContext1");

     string AppValue = configuration.GetSection("RSMDataContext1").Value;

}
```

Comment: Hi, I have done everything that you explained but still seeing the same error.

Comment: I have updated my question as per your response please review.

Comment: Check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/76810311/4527664

Answer (score -1):

I am using .Net Core 6.0, Azure function V4 and appsettings.json. I am able to retrieve connection string.
I deployed my azure function to azure and able to access easily.

Point to be noted use "AddEnvironmentVariables()" under
IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()) //Use Microsoft.Configuration.FileExtensions Nuget Package
.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true) //Use Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json Nuget Package
**.AddEnvironmentVariables()**
.Build();
optionsBuilder.UseMySQL(configuration.GetConnectionString("PortalContext"));

I am attaching screenshot as well
[image]

Please mark this answer as resolved and vote if helped you